# In Kotlin, are there graceful ways of passing values from one instance to another, which have the same name?

Tags: kotlin

I have the following classes

```
class A(
  val value1: String,
  val value2: String,
  val value3: String,
  val value4: String,
  val value5: String,
)

class B(
  val value1: String,
  val value2: String,
  val value3: String,
  val value4: String,
  val value5: String,
) {

  compaion object {
    from(a: A) = B(
      value1 = a.value1,
      value2 = a.value2,
      value3 = a.value3,
      value4 = a.value4,
      value5 = a.value5,
    )
  }
}
```

I write codes as follows when I want to create an instance of B from A

```
val a: A = getAFromSomewhere()
val b: B = B.from(a)
```

I have a lot of codes as above and It's very boring for me to write the factory method, 'from'. Is there any easy way of writing this kind of codes in Kotlin??

Comment: Why do you have two classes with exactly the same properties in the first place?

Comment: @Sweeper this is just a sample code for the sake of simplicity but I actually have classes that have the same name of properties in different layers and they need to be converted to others... The purpose is separation of layers. They generally don't have exactly same properties, but many of them are the same.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You might be interested in the `MapStruct` library.

https://mapstruct.org/

It helps map between two objects(DTO, Entity, etc..).

### Code

In this example we want to map between a Person (Model) and a PersonDto (DTO).

```kotlin
data class Person(var firstName: String?, var lastName: String?, var phoneNumber: String?, var birthdate: LocalDate?)
```

```kotlin
data class PersonDto(var firstName: String?, var lastName: String?, var phone: String?, var birthdate: LocalDate?)
```

The MapStruct converter:

```kotlin
@Mapper
interface PersonConverter {

    @Mapping(source = "phoneNumber", target = "phone")
    fun convertToDto(person: Person) : PersonDto

    @InheritInverseConfiguration
    fun convertToModel(personDto: PersonDto) : Person

}
```

Usage:

```kotlin
val converter = Mappers.getMapper(PersonConverter::class.java) // or PersonConverterImpl()

val person = Person("Samuel", "Jackson", "0123 334466", LocalDate.of(1948, 12, 21))

val personDto = converter.convertToDto(person)
println(personDto)

val personModel = converter.convertToModel(personDto)
println(personModel)
```

From: https://github.com/mapstruct/mapstruct-examples/tree/master/mapstruct-kotlin